# Creating Multiple Client and One Server for UDP application using select() system call with C

Tags: c, sockets, udp

Help me to correct this program I want to create a server that can run indefinitely and can serve many clients and for that, I am using a select system call for UDP (User Datagram Protocol) application.
My issue is that this code is running for multiple clients in a different session that means after running for one client it stops and again when I start the server again then it can serve another client also.
I want my code to work indefinitely in one session only and serve as many clients as I want.

```
Server Code:-
'''

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/select.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    
    #define port1 8080
    #define MAXN 1024
    #define TRUE 1
    
    int main(){
    int sockfd,sockfd1;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
    char buffer[MAXN];
    char buff[MAXN];
    int max_clients=2,valread,new_socket;
    char *hello = "Hello Client";
    char *message = "hiiii Server";
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 20;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    
    
    
    //create socket 2
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if(sockfd<0){
    perror("Error Creating Socket0");
    exit(1);
    }
    //memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
        //memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));
         
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port1);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    
    
    if(bind(sockfd, (const *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))<0){
    perror("Error in binding0 ");
    exit(1);
    }
    
    
    
    
    //Use Select......
    //I have created 2 socket having file deescriptor sockfd and sockfd1
    int s;
    int client_socket[2]={0,0};
    fd_set readfds;
    
    while(){
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd,&readfds);
    //Let's say sockfd is max_fd
    int max_fd = sockfd,sd,activity;
    
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    sd = client_socket[i];
    if(sd>0){
    FD_SET(sd,&readfds);
    }
    if(sd>max_fd)
    max_fd = sd;
    
    }
    
    
    
    activity = select( max_fd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , &timeout);  
           
            if ((activity < 0))  
            {  
                printf("select error");  
            }  
              int   addrlen = sizeof(servaddr);
            //If something happened on the master socket ,  
            //then its an incoming connection  
            if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &readfds))  
            {  
                //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands  
                printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d\n " , new_socket , inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr) , ntohs
                      (servaddr.sin_port));  
               
                //send new connection greeting message  
                if( send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0) != strlen(message) )  
                {  
                    perror("send");  
                }  
                     
                puts("Welcome message sent successfully");  
                     
                //add new socket to array of sockets  
                for (int i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)  
                {  
                    //if position is empty  
                    if( client_socket[i] == 0 )  
                    {  
                        client_socket[i] = new_socket;  
                        printf("Adding to list of sockets as %d\n" , i);  
                             
                        break;  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
                 
            //else its some IO operation on some other socket
            for (int i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)  
            {  
                sd = client_socket[i];  
                     
                if (FD_ISSET( sd , &readfds))  
                {  
                    //Check if it was for closing , and also read the  
                    //incoming message  
                    if ((valread = read( sd , buffer, 1024)) == 0)  
                    {  
                        //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print  
                        getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr , \
                            (socklen_t*)&addrlen);  
                        printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n" ,  
                              inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr) , ntohs(servaddr.sin_port));  
                             
                        //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse  
                        //close( sd );  
                        client_socket[i] = 0;  
                    }  
                         
                    //Echo back the message that came in  
                    else
                    {  
                        //set the string terminating NULL byte on the end  
                        //of the data read  
                        buffer[valread] = '\0';  
                        send(sd , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );  
                    }
    
                   
                }
    }  
    
    }
    
         return 0;
    
    }
    '''
    
    This is one of the Client Code and this code is running :-
    '''
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
     
    #define PORT     8080
    #define MAXN 1024
     
    // Driver code
    int main() {
        int sockfd;
        char buffer[MAXN];
        char *hello = "Hello from Multipleclient";
        struct sockaddr_in     servaddr;
     
        // Creating socket file descriptor
        if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
            perror("Error in socket creation");
            exit(1);
        }
     
        memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
         
        // Filling server information
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
         
        int n, len;
         
        sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello),
            MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,  
                sizeof(servaddr));
        printf("Hello message sent.\n");
             
        n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXN,  
                    MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
                    &len);
        buffer[n] = '\0';
        printf("Server : %s\n", buffer);
     
        close(sockfd);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is `new_socket`? Why don't you delete the `accept` code because UDP doesn't use `accept`? What happened to the indentation when you check for "Goodbye"?

Comment: accept() is commented

Comment: Yes, why do we need to see the commented code?

Comment: and i was trying to add a terminating condition when using while loop.

Comment: Actually i have posted question for first time i will remove these commented code from now.

Comment: If you can correct it i would be very thankful to you.

Comment: Please fix the code formatting and use **consistent** indentation.  The code as currently posted is all but unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

**Some minor things to start with:**

In the client code, you do not initialize `len` before passing it to `recvfrom`. Also, it is of the wrong type (`int` instead of `socklen_t`). This can be corrected by defining `len` as `socklen_t len = sizeof(servaddr);` However, since you do not use the length or address anywhere, you can just pass in `NULL` for both. Also, UDP does not support `MSG_WAITALL`, so pass `0` instead for the flags. `recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXN, 0, NULL, NULL)`.

In the client code, you fill in the server IP address as `IPADDR_ANY`, i.e. `0.0.0.0`, which is only valid when calling `bind`. You are calling `sendto`. When specifying a destination address, you probably want `IPADDR_LOOPBACK` for the local computer.

In the server code, the main `while()` loop is missing a condition inside the parenthesis, so the code does not even compile. You probably want `while(1)` for an infinite loop.

In the server code, in the call to `bind`, you are casting to the wrong type. `(const *)` means `(const int *)`, but you want `(const struct sockaddr *)`.

**The biggest problem:**

Based on the comments and code in the server code, you seem to think that UDP communication has persistent connections, and try to save `client_socket` values for these. However, UDP does not have persistent connection. There is no such thing as a client socket in this context. `select` does not tell you that a new "connection" is ready. Instead, it tells you that data has been received on your one and only UDP socket (`sockfd`). This is entirely unlike TCP, where you `accept` a connection that lasts until one side terminates it.

From the comments in the server code, it seems that you intend for clients to have persistent state in the server, at least enough to be recognized when they send more datagrams (otherwise they would always get the welcome message).

A possible way to make this work is the following:

```
// create and bind a UDP socket as you already do;
// initialize and empty list of clients;
while(1) {
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
    socklen_t cliaddr_len = sizeof(cliaddr);
    recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, bufferlen, /*flags*/ 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &cliaddr_len);

    // check whether cliaddr is in your list;
    if (!is_in_list) {
        // this is a new client
        // add to list of clients;
        // send welcome message;
    }

    // do something else, maybe echo back the buffer contents;
}
```

You will notice that the code does not actually use `select` anymore. `select` is unnecessary if you have nothing to do while waiting, and you only listen to one socket. If you are doing other stuff not shown in the question, you can add the `select` back at the top of the infinite loop, and only handle the UDP socket if `sockfd` is set in the `readfds` from `select`.

Also note that the client cannot actually receive answers from the server, since there is no persistent connection, and the client has not passed any socket to `bind`. And also note that UDP messages may get lost without warning, and you should make sure your code can deal with that. It seems that this client-server-strategy would be easier to implement using TCP.

As a side note, it is strongly recommended to enable warnings in your compiler. That would have caught the wrong type for the address length variables, as well as told you that `new_socket` is used but never set. It is polite to fix all warnings before posting a question, unless of course the question is about the warning.

Comment: @RahulKumarDubey - If this answer is helpful to you, an up-click is the de facto way here to say thank you.

Comment: I added a few more problems related to answers to the client.